# Fix corrupt png (truncated data) in PHP

Tags: php, php-gd

I have a png which is supposedly corrupt, but still loads in all desktop image viewers, but not php.

The error when calling `imagecreatefrompng` is:

> Warning: imagecreatefrompng(): gd-png: fatal libpng error: Read Error:
>   truncated data in test.php on line 45
>
> Warning: imagecreatefrompng(): gd-png error: setjmp returns error
>   condition in test.php on line 45
>
> Warning: imagecreatefrompng(): 'test.png' is not a valid PNG file in
>   test.php on line 45

[image: Here is the image in question] is there anyway of fixing the image in PHP before further processing it? I can fix it by opening it a desktop image viewer and then re-saving as png, but I need to fix any images server side as they come in with this corrupt format.

```
pngcheck test.png
test.png  file doesn't end with an IEND chunk
```

Answer (score 1):

Section 11.2.1 of the [PNG standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11CcGen) under the section critical chunks says

> A valid PNG datastream shall begin with a PNG signature, immediately
> followed by an IHDR chunk, then one or more IDAT chunks, and shall end
> with an IEND chunk. Only one IHDR chunk and one IEND chunk are allowed
> in a PNG datastream.

As the error says the image does not have an IEND chunk. It is not a valid PNG image, and PHP has every right to refuse to process the image.

With that said, how are the images coming to you. Are you connecting to another system to retrieve the images, pulling them from a database, or are they being uploaded by the user?

Comment: they are being generated by a tool I have no control over so will always come to me corrupted, so I need to find a CLI tool or similar to fix them (currently fixing them by opening in desktop image tools and re-saving).